# Execute Code when all Test Scripts are executed in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, nunit, nunit-3.0

I need to execute some set of code once all the Test Scripts have been completed executed (Sequentially/ Parallelly)( It should be like ‘After Suite’ in JAVA).
I came across annotation [SetupFixture] and [OneTimeTearDown]. Generally OneTimeTearDown in SetUpFixer should run once, after all the test scripts executions are done. But due to some unknown reason it is not happening.

Please help me if you have faced and resolved this issue earlier.

**I am trying to build framework so [onetimeteardown][SetupFixture] and test class will not be in same project.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally ask you for some sample code, which isn't working. However, your last line seems like the clue to answering your question.

NUnit analyzes **one test assembly** in order to find attributes. The SetUpFixture with a OneTimeTearDown to run after all the tests in the assembly must be in the same assembly.

If you have tests in multiple assemblies and want some code to run after **all** the assemblies have completed you will have to code that yourself. NUnit doesn't provide such a feature.